# Inconsistent offsetHeight behaviour as page renders

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing a problem with the offsetHeight property in JavaScript.

It returns different values every page reload.

I tried to use setTimeout and it works only sometimes. I noticed that incrementing the time to execute the function the error disappears, but this seems to be aleatory.

For debugging I tried to log the value in 3 different ways:

```
console.log(content.offsetHeight);
setTimeout(() => {console.log(content.offsetHeight)});
setTimeout(() => {console.log(content.offsetHeight)}, 1000);
```

The output can be:
493
493
644 or 493
644
644

Depending on render time.
Do you have suggestions?

Thanks for help

Comment: show us more of your code, including html, please

Comment: Yep, Usually happens with images loading. Add the `onload` event so you run javascript after everything is loaded.